# How to do really multithreaded web mining with IE/.Net/C#?

Tags: c#, .net, web-scraping, data-mining, watin

I want to mine large amounts of data from the web using the IE browser. However, spawning lots and lots of instances of IE via WatiN crashes the system. Is there a better way of doing this? Note that I can't simply do `WebRequests` - I really need the browser due to having to interact with JS-driven behaviors on the site.

Comment: *Why* do you need the browser? When making a somewhat unusual request it's always worth providing the reasons.

Comment: @Jon actually, it's far from unusual. Whenever there's a site that's using AJAX, cookies, javascript-driven interactions, having a simple `WebRequest` is not enough.

Comment: Totally agree with Dmitri.  WatiN (or something like it) is essential for reliable web mining.  @Dmitri, do you get the same crashes when you use FireFox in WatiN instead?  Also how many is "lots and lots" of browser instances?

Comment: I have to agree that it seems strange to use the browser if the browser is not necessary AND is crashing the system for your use case. Ajax is not magic - it makes requests too. You can simulate them.

Comment: @JoshJordan, have you actually tried?  I've written tons of mining code to pull stats and the like from sports web sites.  Simulating the javascript/ajax/et al is a **lot** of work.  With WatiN it's trivial.

Comment: Yes. I wouldn't say it's a lot of work, unless you need to have some notion of state, which, I suppose, is up to the particular type of site you're mining. It's just another request to me. I haven't used WatiN, but that's because all I've heard (not much) is that it doesn't scale (as in this question).

Comment: For actual data mining, relying on a browser seems like a really bad idea. It's likely to be far more efficient to find out how to extract the data with normal web requests, and then do so without a browser.

Comment: @Jon, For the sake of discussion, I invite you to try extracting your email from gmail using that technique.

Comment: @Kirk I actually need IE because it's a kind of 'common denominator' of browsers.
@Jon I wish this was possible, but the level of effort in this case is titanic - essentially, writing your own browser.

Comment: @JoshJordan that's right - WatiN doesn't scale beyond a pool of ~9 (in my case) browser instances. For some, this limitation is acceptable, and for *testing* I might live with it. But for live data mining, performance is critical, so I need more instances.

Comment: @Kirk: I'd extract my email from gmail using IMAP instead.

Comment: @Jon, yes yes, I understand google exposes other APIs.  My point was purely illustrative.

Comment: not that i know the api, but couldn't you do multiple tabs in one instance of IE?  Maybe WatiN doesn't support that, dunno

Comment: @Kirk: But that actually illustrated *my* point - which is that most sites which *want* to expose a lot of data don't really make it hard to get.

Comment: @James WatiN doesn't support it. @Jon maybe I'm interested in sites which *do not want* to expose data in an easily consumable way.

Comment: @Dmitri Can you give an example of a web site that makes it hard to get the data you want?

Comment: @Dmitri way overkill, but assuming the parallel IE instances weren't going to be sharing data, I'm guessing you could potentially start N different instances (up til they start failing to start) per machine (VM, physical, etc) and then instruct them to run through a common proxy and you do the data gathering there (assuming the data you need to gather is available looking at the HTTP traffic and you don't need to access the DOM, for instance).

Comment: So you have a collection of IE instances, and WatiN crashes the app when you have more than 9 in the collection? That doesn't sound right to me -- I seem to recall doing something similar with many more instances. Maybe it would be easier to throw power computing power at the problem and solve it that way.

Comment: As for the feasibility of web browser discussion. I few years ago I did a simple test: email address hidden by javascript magic is hard to obtain by HTML parsing, and it's trivial to get by running RegEx against the text rendered by WebBrowser control.

Comment: @James: I'm afraid I need lots of things, including for example forcing these instances to run JavaScript I choose. @Ian: I want my clients to make do with a single, fairly weak (1Gb RAM, etc.) VPS. Don't want to make it costly.

Answer (score 2):

I am mining a lot of pages with WatiN. Actually 30+ in this moment. Of course it takes a lot of resources - about 2.5 GB of RAM but it is almost impossible to do the same with `WebRequest`. I can't imagine myself doing such a thing in reasonable time. With WatiN it takes a couple of hours.

I don't know if it helps you, but I am using webbrowser control to do that. Every instance is a separate process. But, what's I think is more important to you, I tried once to reduce amount of used memory by doing all of it in single process. It's possible to just make separate `AppDomain`'s instead of processes and force them to use the same dll (especially Microsoft.mshtml.dll) instead of loading the same dll separately for each new app domain. I can't remember how to do that now, but it's not hard to google that. What I remember is that everything worked fine and the usage of RAM was decreased significantly, so I think is worth trying.

Comment: I guess I have two questions here. First, say I'm limited to 1Gb RAM for *everything* (the OS, WatiN, SQL Server, etc.). What can I do about it? Second - how many concurrent processes were you running? The fundamental issue right now is that I can't spawn, say, 100 instances of IE.

Comment: As I said, there is 30+ concurrent processes that takes 2.5 GB of RAM. I think 1 GB is enough to run them in separate app domains with shared dll, but I can't say how many more could be run.

Answer (score 1):

What about launching multiple instances of WebBrowser control (it's IE anyway) in a .NET app to process data mining jobs in async manner?

If perf is a problem - splitting the job and pushing it to the cloud might also help.

Comment: Yeah I thought about moving it into the cloud, but somehow I doubt that spawning `WebBrowser` controls is any different to spawning actual instances of IE. Will need to check. Thanks for the idea!

Comment: It's not much different, probably. But you'll have better control of the exceptions and crashes.

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to actually create one process per instance of web browser, this is because web browser is not a managed code, its COM, and there are cases where unmanaged exceptions can not be handled in managed code, and application will certainly crash.

The better thing would be to create a process host that will spawn multiple processes and you can use named pipes or sockets or WCF to communicate between each of the process if you need to.

The best thing would be to create a small SQL Embedded database and you can queue your jobs in it, the mining process can fetch a new request, and post request back to database, and this database can be used to synchronize everything.

Comment: Sync is pain and databases don't scale to multiple machines (esp. embedded). I believe a simple queue would do the trick better for the communication between multiple processes here (MSMQ for a single machine deployment and some cloud or AMQP implementation for the distributed case).

Comment: Yes, I was only suggesting for single machine, for multiple machines, some sort of queue with MSMQ or some distributed communication will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

I had a project where I scraped on the order of 45 million requests (with form submissions) over an extended basis. On a sustained basis, I was scraping with about 20 simultaneous clients and my pipe was the bottleneck.

I used [Selinium Remote-Control](http://seleniumhq.org/projects/remote-control/) after experimenting with writing my own WebClient, WaTiN/WaTiR, and using Microsoft's UI Automation API.

Selenium RC let's you choose your browser. I used Firefox. Setting up the initial scraping scripts took about an hour of experimentation and tuning. Selenium was vastly faster than writing my own code and a lot more robust with little investment. Great tool.

To scale the process, I tried a few different approaches, but ultimately what worked best was sticking each SRC instance in its own stripped down VM and then spawning as many of those as the workstation had ram to support. An equivalent number of SRC instances running native in the host instead of the vms inevitably ground to a halt as I got up to +10 instances. This required more overhead and setup time before a scraping run, but it would run strongly for days, uninterrupted.

Another consideration -- tune your firefox preferences down so no homepage is loading, turn off everything non-essential (spoofing checks, cookies if not required for your scrape, images, adblock and flashblock, etc).